# MongoDB Flatten Embedded Document from find() Operation

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

I have seen several posts regarding this, but none seem to achieve what i'm looking for.  I have a collection, which I query and receive documents that have data in the root level document and then data in an embedded document; I want to selectively access and return only several fields from both the root level and the embedded, but I want it all to be in a root level document.  I am using mongoengine and pymongo.

For example see the below code:

```
return self.test_collection.find({'Date': {'$gte': start_date}, 'Date': {'$lte': end_date},
                                                    'customer': {'$in': customers}},
                                                   {'Date': 1, 'Time': 1, 'ID': 1,
                                                    'customer': 1, 'style': 1, 'price': 1, 'qty': 1,
                                                    'product.code': 1, 'product.vendor': 1})
```

The above currently returns akin to `{date, time, id, customer, style, price, qty, product {code, vendor}}` where I'm looking for `{date, time, id, customer, style, price, qty, code, vendor}`  This is a large collection that needs to be queried and I really don't want to need to pull the values I want out of each document.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

use the aggregation pipeline with your filter as the `$match` expression. In the projection step, you can map an expression to a field using dictionary syntax. Contrast this with the syntax you already have where each field is a key in a dictionary with value equaling 1.

example code (should work, but might not as I don't have access to your database, and thus have not tested)

```
selection = {
    'Date': {'$gte': start_date, '$lte': end_date},
    'customer': {'$in': customers}
    }

projection = {
    'Date': 1, 
    'Time': 1, 
    'ID': 1,
    'customer': 1, 
    'style': 1, 
    'price': 1, 
    'qty': 1,
    'product_code': '$product.code', 
    'product_vendor': '$product.vendor'
    }

self.test_collection.aggregate([
    {'$match': selection},
    {'$project': projection}
])
```